# Django throws internal 500 error while saving heavy data in session variable

Tags: python-2.7, session-variables, internal-server-error, django-1.5

I am trying to filter some values and holding these values in session variable for writing these values in a excel sheet and also for endless pagination.Some times the query set values reaches nearly 55000.that time django shows internal server error.

views.py

```
def search(request,template='admin/search.html', page_template='pagination/paginate_student.html'):
    rg = request.POST.get
    skill = rg('skills')
    students_list = []
    ec_students = EcStudentProfile.objects.filter(Q(Technical_skills__icontains=skill))
    cs_students= CsStudentProfile.objects.filter(Q(jobrole__icontains=skill))
    me_students = MeStudentProfile.objects.filter(
                Q(jobrole__icontains=skill))
    results = list(chain(ec_students, cs_students, me_students))
    for result in results:
        students_list.append(result)
    if students_list:
        request.session['list'] = students_list
        students_list = request.session['list']
    if 'excel' in request.POST:
        students_list = request.session['list']
        response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/vnd.ms-excel')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=Report.xlsx'
        xlsx_data = WriteToExcel(students_list)
        response.write(xlsx_data)
        return response
    if request.is_ajax():
        students_list = request.session['list']
        template = page_template

    return render_to_response(template,
                              {'page_template': page_template, 'students_list': students_list}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: did you try `StreamingHttpResponse`? here a nice article: https://andrewbrookins.com/django/how-does-djangos-streaminghttpresponse-work-exactly/

Comment: When i remove the code to save in a session variable its rendering fine.I need to hold the data because when i try to click load more pagination or click export as excel button the `request.POST.get` returns null and so final list also will be empty list.Is there any other method for hold the values.